# Testing redis key expiration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, redis

I was wondering if anyone has a clever way of testing behavior after a redis key expires. I am essentially building a small redis backed cache for my application and would like to test what happens after a redis key is set to expire.

I am using rspec as my testing framework. I tried to use Timecop to change the time during testing but realized that it would only effect the testing frame work and not the external redis server.

I can set the TTL to 1 and then use a sleep(1) but I would rather not introduce sleeps into my tests.

Does anyone have a good way of testing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not use http://redis.io/commands/expire to expire the key right away?

Comment: It's amazing how the simplest answer is sometimes the most elusive.

Comment: Do you mean to set the expiration time to zero?

Comment: How do you expire the key immediately?  I tried setting it to zero and nil with SETEX, but both throw an error

Comment: On regular EXPIRE negative values works for me and makes expire immediately. So use EXPIRE key -1 :)

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to fix this for the testing environment is to mock out the redis client and have it return the expected value. I have confidence redis will do the right thing and is implemented correctly so mocking this interaction out is probably better than letting the test actually hit redis.

```
redis_client.should_receive(:ttl).with(key).then_return(-1)
```

or just mock out the request for the key

```
redis_client.should_receive(:get).with(key).then_return(nil)
```

With the newer RSpecs version,

```
expect(redis_client).to receive(:get).with(key).and_return(value)
```